# How can I remove page titles without removing the link in the navigation bar in twentyeleven?

Tags: functions

I 'd like to remove the titles from every page in my blog. But the title in de navigation balk must stay of course. Any idea?

Please explain as easy as possible :-) cause I 'm taking my first steps in the Wordpress world.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the_title(); section from the following templates:

- content-aside.php
- content-featured.php
- content-gallery.php
- content-image.php
- content-intro.php
- content-link.php
- content-page.php
- content-quote.php
- content-single.php
- content-status.php
- content.php

Open the files and look for this:

```
<h2 class="entry-title">
  <a href="<?php 
    the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 
    the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
  <?php the_title(); ?></a>
</h2>
```

The content will vary a little from template to template, just remove everything between the "entry-title" class to remove all titles from displaying in the pages.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it works.